# Variable apparently not defined when it is

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

Having an issue with a function I created in a separate file.

Here's my root program:

```
#Import TKINTER toolset:
from tkinter import *
from mousexy import *

#Starting variables:
#Defining mouse x and y coordinates

global mouse_x
global mouse_y
mouse_x = 0
mouse_y = 0

#Main window:
window = Tk()
window.title = ("Solomon's animation tool")

#Workspace and Canvas:
global wrkspace
wrkspace =  Frame(window, bg="red",width=640,height=480)
global canvas
canvas = Canvas(wrkspace,bg="white",width=640,height=480)

#Keyframe editor: (DO LATER)

#Test for finding mouse xy
canvas.bind("<Button-1>",find_mouse_xy)

wrkspace.pack()
canvas.pack()

#Runs window:
window.mainloop()
```

and here's my function in a separate file (mousexy.py)

```
def find_mouse_xy(event):
    mouse_x = canvas.winfo_pointerx()
    mouse_y = canvas.winfo_pointery()
    print ("x: " + str(mouse_x))
    print ("y: " + str(mouse_y))
```

when I run my root program and click, the console tells me that `canvas` is not defined when it clearly is, what am I doing wrong?

```
mouse_x = canvas.winfo_pointerx()
NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SOLLUU\Documents\Python\Animation software\mousexy.py", line 2, in find_mouse_xy
    mouse_x = canvas.winfo_pointerx()
NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Please share the *full traceback* of the error.

Comment: Globals are *per module*, `mousexy` won't have the same globals.

Comment: Last but not least, when Python throws a `NameError` exception, the name is clearly *not* defined. Not in the place Python is looking.

Answer (score 1):

`find_mouse_xy` is looking for `mousexy.canvas`. You defined `__main__.canvas`. They are two entirely separate variables.

What you probably want is

```
def find_mouse_xy(event):
    # Coordinate of the mouse when the event occurred.
    mouse_x = event.x
    mouse_y = event.y
    # What object was clicked? This handler could
    # be attached to many different widgets in your program.
    where = event.widget
    # ...
```

Comment: so how do i fix it? Sorry I'm really bad with stuff think this.

Comment: That depends on how you are using `find_mouse_xy`. However, I suspect the information the function needs is found in the `event` object passed to it.

Comment: Okay, so how do I get the canvas variable to work with mousexy?